# A field or property with the name 'OrderID' was not found on the selected data source

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview, aspxgridview

Working on Multilevel grid view in asp.net, getting this error continuously. Binding the list is causing this error.  The GridViewOrder is not getting the OrderID property but i have defined it.

The code for classes are:

```
 public class Customer
    {
        public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    }
```

The function calling inner  grid is:

```
 protected void GridViewCustomer_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
            {
                if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    string customerID = GridViewCustomer.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
                    GridView GridViewOrders = (GridView)e.Row.FindControl("GridViewOrders");
                   var lstOrders = from orders in SortCustomer()
                                            where orders.CustomerID == customerID
                                            select orders.Orders;
                    GridViewOrders.DataSource = lstOrders.ToList();
                    GridViewOrders.DataBind(); // This line generating error
                }
            }
```

The aspx code is as:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Orders">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:GridView ID="GridViewOrders" runat="server" 
                             AutoGenerateColumns="False" >

                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderID" HeaderText="Order Id" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderDate" HeaderText="Order Date" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Total" HeaderText="Total" DataFormatString="{0:c}" />
                            </Columns>


                        </asp:GridView>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Where is Order class?

Comment: Is the property name OrderID or OrderId?

Answer (score 2):

You need `SelectMany` here, cause currently you are trying to bind `GridView` to a list of lists of orders:

```
var lstOrders = SortCustomer().Where(c => c.CustomerID == customerID)
                              .SelectMany(c => c.Orders);
```